# Working with preallocated arrays in Matlab's mex function

Tags: matlab, mex

I wrote a simple mex function which updates already allocated by Matlab array:

mex_test_array.c

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    x[0] = 3.1416;
}
```

Test 1:

```
>> y = zeros(2, 2);
>> mex_test_array(y);
>> y

y =

    3.1416         0
         0         0
```

Test 2:

```
>> y = zeros(2, 2);
>> mex_test_array(y(:, 1));
>> y

y =

     0     0
     0     0
```

Why it doesn't work on sub-matrix (Test 2) ? Is it possible to make it work?

Please advise.

Remark:
I understand, that updating input arrays is not how mex files are expected to be writted, and I do know how to return arrays from mex.
The reason I tried this technique is to avoid allocation of the arrays' memory twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *shouldn't* work, since **MATLAB does not want "right-hand-side parameters" to change**. See for example [the online help](http://www.mathworks.de/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#mexFunction):

> prhs [is an] Array of pointers to input data. The input data is read-only and
>   should not be altered by your mexFunction .

That is why your function header

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

says `const mxArray *prhs[]` and not `mxArray *prhs[]`. If you want to return a value, you *are supposed* to do that through `mxArray *plhs[]`. I think the behaviour for when you change a "right-hand-side parameter" is just undefined and recommend reading the full [MEX files guide](http://www.mathworks.de/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html) for further details.

**UPDATE**

**To answer your actual question**,  I assume that when you hand `y` to your function, MATLAB hands you the actual pointer and (falsely) trusts you not to mess with it; when you hand your function `y(:,1)`  MATLAB makes a copy of that part of the array and hands you a pointer to that copy, which is discarded after your function call.

**If you do insist** on doing this, at least read [Matlab mex in-place editing](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-mex-in-place-editing/) on Undocumented Matlab, as pointed out in the comments by [reve_etrange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388184/reve-etrange)! Essentially, you must run

```
mxUnshareArray(const_cast<mxarray *>(prhs[0]), true);
```

before you modify that array. Otherwise running

```
>> y = zeros(2, 2);
>> y_backup=y;
>> mex_test_array(y);
```

will result in

```
>> y    
y =    
    3.1416         0
             0         0
>> y_backup
y =    
    3.1416         0
             0         0
```

... which makes for some hell-of-a-unmaintainable code!

Comment: However, there are [undocumented internal functions](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-mex-in-place-editing/) which allow you to operate on `mxArray`s "in-place."

Comment: Jonas, I added remark to my question (I know this is not unconventional way). From your answer "when you hand your function y(:,1) MATLAB makes a copy of that part of the array" I assume that there is nothing to do to allow pass mex a pointer to actual y(:,1)?