# Unexpected slowdown of function that modifies array in-place

Tags: performance, matlab

This bug is due to Matlab being too smart for its own good.

I have something like

```
for k=1:N
    stats = subfun(E,k,stats);
end
```

where `stats`is a `1xN`array, `N=5000` say, and `subfun` calculates `stats(k)`from `E`, and fills it into stats

```
function stats = subfun(E,k,stats)
    s = mean(E);
    stats(k) = s;
end
```

Of course, there is some overhead in passing a large array back and forth, only to fill in one of its elements. In my case, however, the overhead is negligable, and I prefer this code instead of

```
for k=1:N
    s = subfun(E,k);
    stats(k) = s;
end
```

My preference is because I actually have a lot more assignments than just `stats`.
Also some of the assignments are actually a good deal more complicated.

As mentioned, the overhead is negligable. But, if I do something trivial, like this inconsequential if-statement

```
for k=1:N
    i = k;
    if i>=1
        stats = subfun(E,i,stats);
    end
end
```

the assignments that take place inside subfun then suddenly takes "forever" (it increases much faster than linearly with N). And it's the assignment, not the calculation that takes forever. In fact, it is even worse than the following nonsensical `subfun`

```
function stats = subfun(E,k,stats)
    s = calculation_on_E(E);
    clear stats
    stats(k) = s;
end
```

which requires re-allocation of stats every time.

Does anybody have the faintest idea why this happens?

Comment: What is `E`? Just some constant data?

Comment: `E` might well be constant, or random, yes. Its size does not change. See my edit.

Comment: The JIT of recent versions of Matlab knows not to create a new array, but to do modifications [in-place](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/). One of the requirements is that you define a function as `function x = modify(x, y)` and not `function x_out = modify(x_in, y)`. Your examples seem to follow this rule, but did you check your real code?

Comment: As @Bas mentions, MATLAB has some heuristics built into it to determine whether an array can be modified in-place. I'm guessing that by adding a branch in the loop, you've confused the JIT and it no longer thinks in-place modification is possible, leading to reallocation every iteration. Given that MATLAB has no notion of *reference* parameters to functions you really should rewrite the function so you're calling `stats(k) = subfun(E,k);` within the loop. That would be better practice instead of relying on the JIT and its pattern matching (or whatever it does).

Comment: @Praetorian I've pondered this, but the problem is that my stats is actually a struct containing multiple arrays. I can of course have an array of structures, but I find it more awkward to get the fields from such an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed by others, the problem almost certainly lies with JIT and its relatively fragile ability to modify in place.

As mentioned, I really prefer the first form of the function call and assignments, although other workable solutions have been suggested. Without relying on JIT, the only way this can be efficient (as far as I can see) is some form of passing by reference.

Therefore I made a class `Stats` that inherits from handle, and which contains the data array for `k=1:N`. It is then passed by reference.

For future reference, this seems to work very well, with good performance, and I'm currently using it as my working solution.

Answer (score 5):

This might be due to some obscure detail of Matlab's [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). The JIT of recent versions of Matlab knows not to create a new array, but to do modifications [in-place](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/) in some limited cases. One of the requirements is that the function is defined as

```
function x = modify_big_matrix(x, i, j)
x(i, j) = 123;
```

and not as

```
function x_out = modify_big_matrix(x_in, i, j)
x_out = x_in;
x_out(i, j) = 123;
```

Your examples seem to follow this rule, so, as Praetorian mentioned, your `if` statement might prevent the JIT from recognizing that it is an in-place operation.

If you really need to speed up your algorithm, it is possible to modify arrays in-place [using your own mex-functions](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-mex-in-place-editing/). I have successfully used this trick to gain a factor of 4 speedup on some medium sized arrays (order 100x100x100 IIRC). This is however [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9845097/2647279), could segfault Matlab if you are not careful and might stop working in future versions.

Comment: You do mean `function x = modify(x, y)` and not simply `x = modify(x, y)`, right?

Comment: Yes, my real code also has the required format. Although I would assume that it is JIT that messes up, it is truly strange that the if-statement should do it.